# Scrollable container not scrolling on top of layered layout

Tags: codenameone

In the code below, I can't get the scrollable container scroll at all. What am I missing?

```
    public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form f = new Form(new LayeredLayout());
    Container cont = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    cont.setScrollableX(true);
    for (int x=0; x<20; x++) {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(lbl, FontImage.MATERIAL_APPS, 20);
        cont.add(lbl);
    }
    f.addAll(new Container(), BorderLayout.south(cont));
    f.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug Steve fixed on Friday just after the latest update came out. We'll push out an update by the end of the week with this fix.